# How to link exe with dll at runtime in SCons

Tags: dll, runtime, scons

I have following code in SCons:

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['/W1', '/EHsc', '/O2', '/MD'])

boost_include = 'C:/Boost160'
boost_libs = 'C:/Boost160/libs'
boost_bin = 'C:/Boost160/lib64-msvc-14.0'

env.Append( CPPPATH = boost_include, LIBPATH = [boost_libs, boost_bin] )

tests = []
tests += env.Program( 't', 'src/test1.cpp')
tests += env.Program( 't2', 'src/test2.cpp')

for test in tests:
    command = env.Command( None , test, '$SOURCE > $TARGET' )
    AlwaysBuild(command)
```

It's goal is to print tests created with `boost::test`. However until I copy `boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_60.dll` to the folder containing exe there is an error about missing dll. With dll copied it works obviously, but is there any trick to "link" the dll to exe so it knows where it is at runtime? Mentioned dll is in `boost_bin` directory. My test file is:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Test1
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

bool isEven(int a) {
    return a % 2 != 0;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( isEven(1) == true );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test2 )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( isEven(2) == false );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test3 )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( isEven(3) == true );
}
```

**EDIT**

My tests are running after adding `env.AppendENVPath('PATH', boot_bin)` line. However they can't be executed from `cmd` later as there is no proper lib in `PATH`.

I'm still looking for platform independent solution though.

Comment: Do you know how to do this without SCons involved (on the command line only)? And is this question Windows specific, or not? In the former case you're probably looking for things like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx ...

Comment: I would prefer os independent solution but I can always just check system type. I don't know how to do it woiut or without SCons. I need to configure this with this particular tools. That's why I'm asking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a cross platform solution to this issue as the ways that shared libraries are referenced/located in the binaries varies by platform.

Assuming you are only working with win32/64 and linux you can use two flavors of logic to do so. (Code below is untested)

```
import sys
env = Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['/W1', '/EHsc', '/O2', '/MD'])

boost_include = 'C:/Boost160'
boost_libs = 'C:/Boost160/libs'
boost_bin = 'C:/Boost160/lib64-msvc-14.0'

env.Append( CPPPATH = boost_include, LIBPATH = [boost_libs, boost_bin] )

if sys.platform != 'win32':
    env.Append(RPATH = [boost_libs, boost_bin])
else:
    env.Install('.',env.Glob(boost_libs+"/*.dll")+env.Glob(boost_bin+"*.dll"))

tests = []
tests += env.Program( 't', 'src/test1.cpp')
tests += env.Program( 't2', 'src/test2.cpp')

for test in tests:
    command = env.Command( None , test, '$SOURCE > $TARGET' )
    AlwaysBuild(command)
```

One thing to note is that there is an scons users mailing list where you are likely to get more eyes with scons knowledge on any issues you might have. ( https://pairlist4.pair.net/mailman/listinfo/scons-users )

Comment: As far as I know `RPATH` is not available for all compilers. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which compilers are you using?  Barring that you can set env['ENV']['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] to point to your boost libs.. or perhaps copy them next to the executables.

Comment: Your solution works fine. I've read `!=` as `==`. Do you know any trick which would only link my program to original boost_unit_test dll on windows? Copying is not really what I want. However I'm not even sure if this is possible. If not then I will accept your answer as it is.

Comment: As far as I know copying the dll is the preferred solution. Setting PATH may also work. (It's been a while since I worked on win32)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for help then.